# What is the MATLAB equivalent of Excel's NORMSDIST function?

Tags: excel, matlab, worksheet-function

What is the MATLAB equivalent of Excel's [NORMSDIST](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/827369) function?

Comment: I think `norminv` or `normcdf` are what you are looking for.

Comment: I was leaning towards normcdf, any extra votes out there. Thanks for looking into this @David

Comment: Read the documentation and it should become clear ;)

Comment: Based on what you are suggesting, I am going with the second one after trying to understand the docs. I am no math expert here. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is [Normcdf](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=91269). Excel have enhanced the accuracy of some statistical functions and in Excel 2013 the output of:

```
=NORMSDIST(-5.5)
```

is `1.8989562465887700E-08`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MATLAB function for probability of failure: `1-normcdf(x)`
or `normcdf(-x)`